# Media doesn't respect user agent

Tags: ios, cordova

I’m setting a custom user agent in iOS using the following code (in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`):

```
// User agent
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@“CustomAgent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

This works perfectly for all network requests. However, when I create a `var media = new Media(url); media.play();`. It respects it in the emulator, but not on the device.

From Device:

`"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D201 (341099536)”`

From Emulator:

`"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11D167CustomAgent (4474555984)”`

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/src/ios/CDVSound.m#L393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to override the user agent by overriding the `userAgent` function in `CDVViewController`:

```
- (NSString*)userAgent
{
    if (_userAgent == nil) {
        //NSString* originalUserAgent = [CDVUserAgentUtil originalUserAgent];
        _userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CustomAgent"];
    }
    return _userAgent;
}
```